# determine if a model attribute is empty in yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

```
            'buttons'=>array(
            'catalog'=>array(
                'label'=>'Catalog tehnic',
                'imageUrl' => strlen($data->catalog) > 1 ?  Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/pdf.jpg" : Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/bw.png",
                'url'=>'$data->catalog',
            ),
```

i am trying to set different icons for a button in cgridview buttoncollumn if a value is set or not. 
i have tried different things as following all whit same result.

```
                'imageUrl' => strlen($data->catalog) > 1 ?  Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/pdf.jpg" : Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/bw.png",
                'imageUrl' => isset($data->catalog)  ?  Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/pdf.jpg" : Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/bw.png",
                'imageUrl' => !empty($data->catalog) ?  Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/pdf.jpg" : Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/bw.png",
                'imageUrl' => $data->catalog == '' ?  Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/pdf.jpg" : Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/bw.png",
                'imageUrl' => !$data->catalog ?  Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/pdf.jpg" : Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/bw.png",
```

it is geting very frustrating so pls help me out guys. thx in advance

Comment: try with is_null( $data->attribute )

Comment: it returns everything as true as whit my other attempts. if i do any of the checks at the 'visible' array element they all work correctly, but at the 'imageurl' element they all return either true or false. i'm very confused and they only explanation i can find is that yii can't do a check over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CButtonColumn` class render buttons on default generated `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView`.

Reading class code, only `url` and `visible` properties [can be evaluated as PHP expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).

`imageUrl` property in this class is processed as plain string (not PHP expression).

I made this experiment. Suggestions are totally welcome. I hope it helps you:

Create in `protected/components` a new class: for example `ExtCButtonColumn.php`. This class should inherit class `CButtonColumn`.

```
class ExtCButtonColumn extends CButtonColumn
{
...
}
```

In class code, rewrite rendering method, keeping original concept and avoiding break existing or legacy implementations on other `CGridViews`:

```
protected function renderButton($id,$button,$row,$data)
{
    if (isset($button['visible']) && !$this->evaluateExpression($button['visible'],array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data)))
            return;
        $label=isset($button['label']) ? $button['label'] : $id;
        $url=isset($button['url']) ? $this->evaluateExpression($button['url'],array('data'=>$data,'row'=>$row)) : '#';
        $options=isset($button['options']) ? $button['options'] : array();
        if(!isset($options['title']))
           $options['title']=$label;

            $imageUrl = isset($button['imageUrl']) ? $this->evaluateExpression($button['imageUrl'],array('data'=>$data,'row'=>$row)) : '';
            if ( $imageUrl == '')
               $imageUrl = isset($button['imageUrl']) ? $button['imageUrl'] : '#';
        if( $imageUrl != '#' )
           echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image($imageUrl,$label),$url,$options);
        else
           echo CHtml::link($label,$url,$options);
    }
```

Finally in your view code, in widget definition ( `$this->widget` array ), in `columns` array , add a similar buttons definition (this is a example with a custom button). Now is possible in all `imageUrl` attributes to use PHP expressions like `url` and `visible` properties:

```
array(
    'class'    => 'ExtCButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{process}{view}{update}{close}{back}',
    'buttons'  => array
     (
        'process' => array
        (
           'label'    => 'Procesar',
           'imageUrl' => 'strlen($data->catalog) > 1  ? Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . "/images/icons/myicon1.png" : Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . "/images/icons/myicon2.png"',   
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
   'imageUrl' => '!empty($data->catalog) ?  Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/pdf.jpg" : Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/bw.png"'
```

or you can do:

```
   'imageUrl' => function($data){
          $url = '';
          if(strlen($data->catalog > 1 ){
             // do stuff
             $url = $data->catalog; // assign url here
          elseif(){
              // implement your logcic here
          }
          elseif{

          }
          return $url;
   }
```

Comment: i have tryed empty, isset, is_null, strlen, !$data->attribute. nothing works, it either returns true or false on all instances.  Alejandro's way works best for what i need. i have actually done that before i've seen his answer but the answer gave me a better perspective

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this now

```
    'imageUrl' => 'strlen($data->catalog) > 1 ?  Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/pdf.jpg" :
 Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/bw.png"',
```

Wrap your code inside  quotes and then it should work for you

Comment: I think one has to use single quotes, double breaks it!

Comment: @tinyByte may be you are right bro but i never faced such a problem.